# How do I find HTML links missing the protocol in the href attribute?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find incorrectly written links like this:

```
<a href="mydomain.com">link</a>
```

I've got this regex:

```
href *= *"? *(?!http|https|ftp)
```

But if doesn't work... any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: In which language are you working? There may be an easier way than using regular expressions that deals with HTML like, `<a title="My Domain" href="mydomain.com">link</a>`...

Comment: What language? You should do this with a DOM parser.

Comment: Rather than looking for particular protocols, you should look for `^(.*?)://`, since you can't have a protocol specified without the `://` portion.

Comment: Thanks - but the problem is the regex isn't capturing the negative lookahead. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using [GNU **`grep`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/):

```
% echo '
<a href="http://mydomain.com">link</a>
<a href="https://mydomain.com">link</a>
<a href="ftp://mydomain.com">link</a>
<a title="My Domain"
   href="mydomain.com">link</a>
' | grep --perl -o 'href[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"(?!(ht|f)tps?://)[^"]+"'
href="mydomain.com"
```